# How does assigning to a borrowed variable violate the rules of references?

Tags: rust, borrowing

I have this code:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    link: &'a i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 33;
    println!("x:{}", x);
    let ff = Foo { link: &x };
    x = 22;
}
```

Which generates this compiler error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `x` because it is borrowed
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
8 |     let ff = Foo { link: &x };
  |                           - borrow of `x` occurs here
9 |     x = 22;
  |     ^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `x` occurs here
```

The Rust book has only two rules:

1. one or more references (`&T`) to a resource,
2. exactly one mutable reference (`&mut T`).

I have one mutable variable and one immutable link. Why does the compiler give an error?

Answer (score 7):

[*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) defines [the rules of references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references):

> - At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any number of immutable references.
> - References must always be valid.

Reassigning a variable implicitly requires a mutable reference:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 33;
    let link = &x;
    x = 22;
    *(&mut x) = 22; // Basically the same thing
}
```

Importantly, reassigning a variable *mutates* the variable, which would cause the value of the **immutable** reference `link` to change, which is disallowed.

Note that the initial assignment of the variable does **not** require the variable to be mutable:

```
fn main() {
    let x;
    // Some other code
    x = 42;
}
```

Comment: Is there any official documentation or tutorial stating that assigning to a variable implicitly requires a mutable reference?

Comment: @Kun I've clarified the wording some; it's really the **re**assignment, which is hopefully more obviously a mutation of a value. Otherwise, not that I'm aware of. In general, many people find it self-evident.

Comment: Thx! I think it makes sense to disallow mutating/reassigning the owner of a borrowed variable (mutably or immutably borrowed), just wish it were better documented in the rust book.